# How can Spark writes larger files without additional data?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

I use Spark EMR to process data and write them to S3. The data are partitioned by date. In the case where we re-process the same date data, I use a custom-made function that compares the ongoing processed dataframe with the data that is already in S3. Both data are fused so that no data is lost.

My issue is that between the first write and the second write of the same data, the total size of the data is different in S3.

The first write results in 200 files of variable sizes (20-100KB) for a total of 74MB. The second write results in 200 files of fixed sizes (about 430KB each) for a total of 84MB.

I compared both data from the different writes by importing them into dataframes, the number of rows is similar. The data are the same (I used df1.exceptAll(df2)).

Why is there a difference in file sizing between first and second writes?
Where could this additional 10MB come from?

I do not use any repartitions / coalesce.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for some reason there are duplicates in the second `df` and your validation doesn't handle that scenario. In that case, you'll need to do the same verification, but inverting your `df`'s.

Sample:

```
import spark.implicits._
val df1 = Seq(
  (1,2,3),
  (4,5,6)
).toDF("col_a", "col_b", "col_c")

val df2 = Seq(
  (1,2,3),
  (4,5,6),
  (4,5,6)
).toDF("col_a", "col_b", "col_c")

df1.show()
df2.show()


// output:

+-----+-----+-----+
|col_a|col_b|col_c|
+-----+-----+-----+
|    1|    2|    3|
|    4|    5|    6|
+-----+-----+-----+

+-----+-----+-----+
|col_a|col_b|col_c|
+-----+-----+-----+
|    1|    2|    3|
|    4|    5|    6|
|    4|    5|    6|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

`exceptAll` validations:

```
df1.exceptAll(df2).show()

+-----+-----+-----+
|col_a|col_b|col_c|
+-----+-----+-----+
+-----+-----+-----+

df2.exceptAll(df1).show()

+-----+-----+-----+
|col_a|col_b|col_c|
+-----+-----+-----+
|    4|    5|    6|
+-----+-----+-----+
```